# Prove that $\dim \ker(H) = 2^{m} -1 -m$

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science, information-theory, coding-theory

> Let $H$, the parity check matrix of the *Hamming code*. $H\in Mat_{m\times 2^{m} - 1}$ where it's columns are all $\mathbb{F}^m \setminus \{o\}$. Prove that the rank of the code is $2^{m} -1 -m$.

let's denote the rank of the code as $k$. Then, $G$ is the generator matrix with the rank of $m+k\times k$. Since $H$ is a mapping from $\mathbb{F}^n$ to $\mathbb{F}^k$ and $G$ is the "opposite" mapping it must be that $m+k = 2^{m}-1 -m$ and therefore $k = 2^{m}-m-1$

Now, as far as I understand $G$ is injective and therefore it's kernel is trivial and so $k = 2^m -1 -m$ is indeed (by the rank-nullity theorem) the rank of the code.

Is that correct? I don't feel that certain about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to check that $H$ has full rank $m$.

The parity check matrix $H$ determines a mapping $\Bbb{F}^n\to\Bbb{F}^m$. If you know that $H$ has full rank, then that mapping is onto, and the code is the kernel which, by rank-nullity, has rank $n-m=2^m-1-m$.

Why has $H$ got full rank? You can surely convince yourself that a subset of columns of $H$ forms an $m\times m$ identity matrix.

Comment: Jyrki, you meant that if you rearranged the columns properly then we will get a series of identity matrices of the size $m\times m$?

Comment: Technically so, I guess:-). As long as the columns of $I_m$ show up there (or any other set of $m$ linearly independent columns for that matter) you are fine!

Comment: Also, assuming $\mathbb F$ is $\{0,1\}$, aren't the first three columns dependent? $(1,0,0) + (0,1,0) + (1,1,0) = (0,0,0)$.

Comment: Yes, they are dependent. But, still there will be some three independent columns (in your case $m=3$). And that is enough to force $H$ to have rank $m$.

Comment: Oh right, thanks again! :)